# Show a minimized, dynamically created Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a program that allows you to open other `Forms` of the application itself.
Each of these `Forms` can be opened via a `PictureBox` and, having a custom title bar, they have a custom button that allows you to minimize them.

You can open more than one of each window.

When minimizing one of these Windows, a `UserControl` is added to a `FlowLayoutPanel` with a custom background image and a `Label` with the text of the minimized Window.

How can I show a specific Window if there are more open ones, maybe with the same title?

Comment: I would be tempted to use the Window Handle and then [ShowWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow). The Handle could be passed to the `UserControl` when the `Form` is minimized. Or you could have a `List` of objects (class) of some kind that keep track of the created forms (for different uses) and connects (or injects) the `UserControl` using a property that identifies a specific `Form`. Maybe, using its Handle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag of the label containing the text of the minimized window can hold a reference to the form.
As the label is created from the code on the form to be minimized...

```
NewLable.Tag = Me
```

Then when you want to reshow the form

```
Private Sub SomeLabel_Click(sender as object, e as EventArgs) Handles SomeLabel.Click 
    Dim frm as Form
    Dim lbl as Lable = CType(sender, Label)
    frm = CType(lbl.Tag, Form)
    frm.Show
End Sub
```

Untested - just an idea

Comment: Casting string to form? `frm = CType(lbl.Tag, Form)`

Comment: @djv  Casting `Object` to `Form`. Have 2 Forms (`Form1` and `Form2`). In `Form1` constructor/load set `[Form1].[SomeLabel].Tag = Form2`. In `[Form1].[SomeLabel].Click()` => `(...) Dim frm As Form = CType(lbl.Tag, Form)` `frm.Show()` will show `Form2`.

Comment: @djv The magic of vb.net Form auto-instances. In C# would be `[SomeLabel].Tag = typeof(Form);` `[SomeLabel].Tag = new Form2();` `Label lbl = sender as Label;` `((Form)lbl.Tag).Show();`.

Comment: @Jimi the Tag property does not do a great job of conveying the intent of the developer. Exhibit 1: my mistake of assuming Tag was a string. As a vessel for the form reference, I suppose it does its job. But what if OP wanted to hide the label when the form was restored from minimization? (I understand that to be the case) It would require the form to be aware of the label as well. Setting up the event handlers when they are both in context gets around this. (I suppose one could also do `CType(lbl.Tag, Form).Tag = lbl`)

Comment: @djv  The OP wants to show a `UserControl` inside a FLP when the a `Form` is minimized. The question might be *how does this Form know of the UC and when the latter is instantiated?* The OP knows it. You are suggesting to use Event Handlers with a Lambda to detect a Form's Window change in state, tying it to UC visible state. She is suggesting to set the inner `Label.Tag` to a `Form` reference. The Lable's Click event may also manage the UC visibility, but, as you note, this won't handle a further change of state of the Form's Window. But, what happens to the UC when a Window is normalized?

Comment: @jimi `When minimizing one of these Windows, a UserControl is added to a FlowLayoutPanel` I understand that every time it is minimized it is added, so logically it must also be removed. So I took it one step further and hid the UC (button) when form is restored. That can be commented if it wasn't required. I use dynamic controls extensively, and sometimes multiple controls need to be aware of each other. I've found that setting up event handlers when they are all in context works very well.

Comment: @djv  Agreed on the event handlers. I, personally, also use `INotifyPropertyChange` quite often. The (quiz) point is the one you quoted. A UC is added (or created? is it already there?) when a Window is minimized. Each time? So, it comes to mind that when the Window state is restored, the UC could be removed/disposed, otherwise... In this case, both answers (Mary's is missing the implementation) will work (almost) the same.

Comment: @djv The Tag property of a Control is an object not a string. If the form being minimized was passed to the tag property it can be casted back to a Form.

Comment: @djv I think the .Tag property of controls is handy as a pants pocket. I often store the Primary Key of a record there or the entire record if it is a class instance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified example

Make a new project with three forms (Form1, Form2, Form3), and make the startup object Form3. On Form3, add FlowLayoutPanel1, and add Button1 and Button2.

Make this the code in Form3. The other forms can be blank.

```
Public Class Form3

    Private forms As New List(Of Form)()

    Private Sub addNewForm(form As Form)
        forms.Add(form)
        Dim b As New Button With {.Text = form.Text, .Visible = False}
        AddHandler b.Click, Sub() form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        AddHandler form.Resize, Sub() b.Visible = (form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized)
        Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b)
        form.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        addNewForm(New Form1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        addNewForm(New Form2)
    End Sub

End Class
```

I think the key is adding a handler for each button added to the FlowLayoutPanel which corresponds to each created form. This way you don't need to try to keep track of the forms, since the button handler is created while the form is still in context.

You can change the buttons to your UserControl or whatever, but the concept will be the same.